# Getting an odd value, so odd

Tags: c, visual-c++

Here 's the related code:

```
            char* url;
            url = "http://xxxx/index.txt";

            TCHAR t_url[256];
            charToTchar(url, t_url);
            downloadFile(t_url);
```

Two functions:

```
            charToTchar(const char *_char, TCHAR *tchar)
            {
                int iLength ;  
                iLength = MultiByteToWideChar (CP_ACP, 0, _char, strlen (_char) + 1, NULL, 0) ;  
                MultiByteToWideChar (CP_ACP, 0, _char, strlen (_char) + 1, tchar, iLength) ;  
            }

            downloadFile(TCHAR *url_value)
            {
                TCHAR path[256];
                SHGetSpecialFolderPath(NULL, path, 28 , false);
                wcscat_s(path,  _T("\\check.txt"));

                char* c_url_value;
                c_url_value = "";

                int iLength ;  
                iLength = WideCharToMultiByte(CP_ACP, 0, url_value, -1, NULL, 0, NULL, NULL);  
                WideCharToMultiByte(CP_ACP, 0, url_value, -1, c_url_value, iLength, NULL, NULL);   

                DeleteUrlCacheEntry(c_url_value);  
                HRESULT hr = URLDownloadToFile(0, url_value, path, 0, 0);
            }
```

The right TCHAR path should look like this:

C.:\......\L.o.c.a.l.\.c.h.e.c.k...t.x.t.

But when I run second time of "downloadFile" function, the TCHAR path became so odd:

C.:\.......\L.o.c.a.l.index.txt.k.t.x.t.

ps I'm using VC++ and I don't think it supports "wcscat_s". Any solutions?

Comment: Why are you jumping back and forth between `char` and `TCHAR`?  They are not the same thing.  The `DelteUrlCacheEntry` takes pointers to `TCHAR`, not `char*`.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383983%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: use the tchar defined method `_tcscat'

Comment: I suggest `url` should be `const char *`

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Because DelteUrlCacheEntry gets error if I pass a char* url. "error C2664: 'DeleteUrlCacheEntry' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'unsigned short *' to 'const char *'"  ps. I'm doing a unicode project.

Comment: @corn3lius Nah... Still gets the odd value.

Comment: @DylanMorison - You get an error for the reasons I stated in the comment.

Comment: @NeilKirk I don't think url has something to do with the odd value problem. But I did tried to use const char* url. The problem stays.

Comment: No it's not to do with the error.

Comment: Why is this marked as C++? It's pure C.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie  Sorry I said it wrong. I got error if I pass TCHAR url value to DeleteUrlCacheEntry(). I can only pass char* url to the function.

Comment: @DylanMorison - Make sure you are indeed 1) Compiling a UNICODE build and 2) You are passing a *pointer* or address, not just a `TCHAR`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the character set type is Unicode, then using char* right from the start is incorrect.

```
        TCHAR url[] = _T("http://xxxx/index.txt");
        DeleteUrlCacheEntry(url);  
        downloadFile(url);
```

The function `DeleteUrlCacheEntry` takes an `LPCTSTR`.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383983%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

The definition of this type depends on the build settings for Visual C++.  If the build is `UNICODE`, then the string type is 16-bit, not 8 bit.

Therefore to be "build neutral", the type to use is `TCHAR` and usage of the `_T` macro to create string constants can be used.

The following program compiles successfully when the character set type chosen is Unicode (Visual Studio 2010):

```
#include <tchar.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <WinInet.h>

int main()
{
    TCHAR url[] = _T("http://xxxx/index.txt");
    DeleteUrlCacheEntry(url);  
}
```

The following program does not compile successfully if a UNICODE build is chosen:

```
#include <tchar.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <WinInet.h>

int main()
{
    char* url = "http://xxxx/index.txt";
    DeleteUrlCacheEntry(url);  
}
```

The error is as follows:

**error C2664: 'DeleteUrlCacheEntryW' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'char *' to 'LPCWSTR'
Types pointed to are unrelated; conversion requires reinterpret_cast, C-style cast or function-style cast**

---

If you know for sure that it's UNICODE and won't ever be any other character set build, you can eschew all of this and just use `std::wstring`, instead of `TCHAR` and `_T`.  Or better yet, you can use a `std::basic_string<TCHAR>` and take advantage of the functions that are available.

Comment: Nobody needs to support windows 98 anymore, there is no reason to use `TCHAR` or `_T` anymore. Just use wide strings.

Comment: @Mgetz - `Nobody` is a big word.  Maybe `most`.  Anyway, my last paragraph emphasizes this.

Comment: I got this: 'DeleteUrlCacheEntry' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'unsigned short [42]' to 'const char *'

Comment: Then you are not compiling a Unicode build.  Look at my edited answer and the small sample program.  It compiles cleanly in Visual Studio 2010 when the character set type is UNICODE.

Comment: Well, I think I　build in UNICODE: Project settings ->c/c++ -> preprocessor definitions-> _UNICODE,UNICODE, right?

Comment: @DylanMorison - No, those are not the settings.  The settings are in "Configuration Properties -> General -> Character Set"

Comment: I think VS2010 is much more tolerable than Visual C++ . A lot of VC errors don't show up in VS, from my experience.

Comment: You are saying the same thing! VC settings is different from VS. I have VS too, I set unicode just like you when using VS.

Comment: @DylanMorison - Then you have a compiler setup issue or a project setup issue.  The `DeleteUrlCacheEntry` takes an `LPCTSTR`, plain and simple.  You cannot pass a `char*` to such function if the build is UNICODE.  What version of Visual Studio are you using?

Comment: Alright. Maybe you are right. But I don't think DeleteUrlCacheEntry is causing the issue. My problem is that TCHAR path has been mixed with some characters.